# Azure table storage - how to create 'contains' condition

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I want to query azure table storage not in default way, f.e.

```
conditions.Add(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("UserRole", QueryComparisons.Equal, userRole));
```

I need some kind of `QueryComparisons.Contains` (as `LIKE` in SQL) that is not present by default.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: hi all, is there any update on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need some kind of QueryComparisons.Contains (as LIKE in SQL) that is
>   not present by default What is the best way to implement this? Thanks

As of today, it is not possible to implement a `Contains` kind of functionality with Azure Tables. You would need to fetch all entities and then do this operation on client side.

At best, you could do something like `StartsWith` with Azure Tables by using a combination of `QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual` and `QueryComparisons.LessThan`.