# Contain and Sort in Azure Table Storage with Node JS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

All,

I am trying to fetch some records via Azure Function using Node JS from a Table Storage.

```
let result = await tableClient.listEntities({
    queryOptions: {filter: odata`PartitionKey eq ${queryFilter}`}
});
```

I tried a lot to find ways to fire a contain and a sort query, I know it can be done via the Table Storage REST API but not able to find the same in Javascript SDK.

Any advice on this one?

Thanks in advance!

SG

Answer (score 0):

Azure table storage doesn't support ordering or sorting in the query as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query#sorting-data-in-the-table-service). However, you can use a combination of filters to narrow down the data returned and make your node js app sort them in memory.

Depending on how you are querying the data, you can probably find an appropriate [design pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns) recommended by Microsoft. It's important to keep in mind that items are ordered in ascending order first by PartitionKey and then by RowKey.

As for a "contains" behavior, [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038116/azure-table-storage-how-to-create-contains-condition) suggests it is not possible, and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators) do not list any contains operator. However, you might be able to get away with using the less-than and greater-than operators to emulate a contains query. Strings are compared in lexicographical order, which means if your column has a string value and you know the starting letters, then you could construct a filter like `myCol gt 'prefix' and myCol lt 'prefixZZZZZZZ'` where "prefix" is whatever the prefix of the string. You padd the prefix with an appropriate amount of Zs so that it causes the lexicographical value to become larger and produce a range.

Ultimately, Microsoft considers CosmosDB it's premium alternative to Azure Table Storage, and CosmosDB supports a contains at a much higher cost.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the sort feature in the Table Storage and now sorting the results in my NodeJS Function app. Any idea about 'contains' query?

Comment: @SSG - There's still nothing that gets 100% parity with a SQL contains filter would do, but I updated my answer to give you more context. I've been using table storage to track millions of time series records, and it works great. It's a very low-cost option, but you really need to think about how you will query the data before writing to it because there are many limitations compared to other databases. You might need to add a meta column that helps you filter, or you might need to break data into multiple columns. The trick us leveraging PartitionKey, RowKey, and other columns in your filter.